# How to make the clock display and the event today behind the search button

Tags: javascript, html, cesiumjs

I set up a table to show the event today and clock display near the Cesium Button. However, when I clicked the Search Button, the search display is behind the clock display. Let me show you an image.
[image]

My code is found below...
HTML file

```
   <div class="toolbar-left2 noselect" style="position:fixed; left: 1085px;top:5px;">-->
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="color:white;"><font size="3">Events Today : </font></td>
                <td id="totalattack" style="color:white;"><font size="3">&nbsp;0</font></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="color:white;"><font size="3">Current Time &nbsp;</font></td>
                <td id="todaylocaltime"style="color:white;"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

so how to put the clock and the event today behind the search display... Please help me. Should i modify the cesium.js code???? Or perform z-index to do this.
Should i modify the geocoder??????If so how to do it??
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can set the z-index of the dom with style `position: fixed`(the table's wrapper) and the search wrapper dom, then the dom of which the z-index has the smaller value will behind the larger.

Comment: i cant control the search wrapper dom. as the code is by default for cesium

Comment: is there a way to set the z-index to the geocoder??

Comment: you can kookup the z-index value of the search wrapper dom,and then set your table's wrapper a higher value of it's z-index.

Comment: i tried the lookup for search wrapper dom in the cesium.js, but I could not find zindex or z-index value.... Even there is a lot of value...

Comment: oh wait never mind, I can solve the problem, i set the style of the .cesium-viewer-geocoderContainer{z-index:1;} and it work...

Comment: thank a lot... I found the '.cesium-viewer-geocoderContainer' from the geocoder.css. and then I modify it